# filtrar resultados mysql

Tags: mysql

tengo una duda en mysql

tengo el siguiente listado y solo quiero filtrar los que no tengan respuesta o estén vacíos

```
ID | RUT | Respuesta|
1  | 111 | si       |
2  | 222 |          |
3  | 333 | si       |
4  | 111 |          |
5  | 222 |          |
```

la respuesta que necesito sería solo el rut 222 (porque no respondió nada)
pero al ejecutar esto

```
select id, rut, respuesta
from tabla
where respuesta = ' ' 
GROUP BY rut
```

pero con esto también me trae el rut 111 (porque tiene una respuesta completa y una vacía)
lo que necesito es que solo me traiga lo que No tiene nada.. espero se explique, he intentado con **where in** y con **DISTINCT** pero no logro dar con el resultado,
saludos y gracias

Comment: SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE `respuesta` = "", asi no funcionara?

Comment: Te interesa traer solo el campo `RUT` o también su respectivo `ID`? Traerías solo UN resultado en este caso o 2?

Comment: Sólo tienes que  agregar un `OR` para filtrar por nulos: `select id, rut, respuesta
from tabla
where respuesta = ' '  or isnull(respuesta)
GROUP BY rut`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No soy muy experto en SQL, pero esta consulta recorre la tabla y por cada registro hace una subconsulta preguntando si valor de `rut` tiene en algún registro que sea diferente a `''` o `NULL` en la columna `Respuesta` en toda la tabla. De ser así, no se cumple el `WHERE` y se omite ese registro.

```
SELECT id, rut, respuesta
FROM tabla
WHERE rut NOT IN (SELECT rut FROM tabla WHERE respuesta > '');
```

Resultado

```
id | rut | respuesta
---+-----+----------
2  | 222 | NULL
5  | 222 | NULL
```

Los registros no necesariamente serán únicos por `rut`, ni porque pongas un `DISTINCT`, porque los `id` son diferentes. Para que sea único por `rut`, tendrás que omitir el campo `id` y poner un `DISTINCT`, o usar `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Muchas gracias, use al final group by y omití el id, nuevamente gracias, un abrazo sanitizado!